# How do I use next auth getServerSession in next js 13 beta server component in app directory

Tags: session, jwt, prisma, next.js13, next-auth

I'm using next auth v4 with next js 13 beta with server component, and everything works fine. But I have a situation where I will need to know the logged user id, since I'm using next auth, I have access to the session, I can use useSession() but then I will need to make the component a client component, So I want to use it on the server, I can use getServerSession in API since I have access to req & res object, but in next js beta with new app dir, I can't do it. Please let me know if you know how to fix the issue. Thank you

```
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { authOptions } from "@/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]";

const Test = async () => {
    const user_id = 1; // How do I get user id from session, user_id is available in session

    // I don't have access req & res object in server component.
    const data = await getServerSession(request, response, authOptions);

    console.log(data);

});
    return (
        <></>
    );
};

export default Test;
```

Didn't find enough information

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found an answer, in next js 13, you wont need to use request & response object, just use the authOptions, it will work

```
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { authOptions } from "@/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]";

const Test = async () => {

    const data = await getServerSession(authOptions);

    console.log(data);

});
    return (
        <></>
    );
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: Mind sharing your authOptions?

Comment: [https://gist.github.com/shakibhasan09/c37eb67910a992f881e722313531b2fb]check this

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Does that link still work?  I am getting 404.

Comment: [https://gist.github.com/shakibhasan09/c37eb67910a992f881e722313531b2fb]

Comment: Another 404 - would you mind sharing your authOptions in the post?

Comment: @DavidConlisk, sure https://gist.github.com/shakibhasan09/c37eb67910a992f881e722313531b2fb

Comment: This displays a message in the server console. Not sure if it's a warning: ``getServerSession` is used in a React Server Component.`

Answer (score 7):

[Docs for Options](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options)

```
import { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth'
```

this is NextAuthOptions type

```
export interface AuthOptions {
  providers: Provider[];
  secret?: string;
  session?: Partial<SessionOptions>;
  jwt?: Partial<JWTOptions>;
  pages?: Partial<PagesOptions>;
  callbacks?: Partial<CallbacksOptions>;
  events?: Partial<EventCallbacks>;
  adapter?: Adapter;
  debug?: boolean;
  logger?: Partial<LoggerInstance>;
  theme?: Theme;
  useSecureCookies?: boolean;
  cookies?: Partial<CookiesOptions>;
}
```

this is how you get session

```
const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
```

Based on AuthOptions interface

```
const authOption: NextAuthOptions = {
  // Since you tagged prisma
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(yourDbConfig),
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  // https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/pages
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: clientId,
      clientSecret: clientSecret,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ token, session }) {
      if (token) {
        // set session here
      }
      return session
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      const dbUser = getUserByTokenEmail

      //add logic here
    },
    
  },
}
```

this is how we use `authOptions` to set up next-auth

```
// app/auth/[...nextauth].ts (I htink after next 13.2)
// pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts before

import { authOptions } from 'folderLocationOfauthOptions'
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'


export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, very detailed. Although, having just started all this, the file structure is causing me some headache. If we're to be migrating away from /pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js, where are all these config and functions supposed to go?

Comment: @mtro this is exactly what I'm trying to understand at the moment as well. Any luck?

Comment: @Laky we are not migrating away `[...nextauth].js`. updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

If you're using app directory in Next 13, and initiating next-auth from Route handlers like this :

`src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js`

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
    })
  ]
})

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

then you can just using `getServerSession` in server components without passing anything

`src/app/layout.js`

```
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth'

...

export default async function Layout ({ children }) {
  const data = await getServerSession()

  return (
    <h5>Data: {JSON.stringify(data)}</h5>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do the same this with the app router, its the same flow except the `authOptions` will be added to `app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.(ts/js)`.