# Nextauthjs const { data: session } = useSession(); in SERVER SIDE Rendering in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth, next.js13

this is my code on page.tsx (Server side rendering)

```
 <NavigationBar session={session} />
```

and passing it to "use client" page using

```
const NavigationBar = ({ session }: any) => {}
```

How to avoid this error I still want my page.tsx as serverside rendering

```
app/page.tsx (17:38) @ useSession

  15 | export default function Home() {
  16 | 
> 17 | const { data: session } = useSession();
     |                                    ^
  18 | 
  19 | 
  20 | return (
```

Comment: did u use the `use client' directive

Comment: Hi Yilmaz I don't want to use "use client" in my home (page.tsx) file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useSession` is react hook. Hooks can be used only in client-side components. The hook is a function that is hooked into the react lifecycle. If you want to use server component, you have to use

```
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";

const ServerComponent = async () => {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  return ()
}
```

for auth options I explained here: [How do I use next auth getServerSession in next js 13 beta server component in app directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75413452/how-do-i-use-next-auth-getserversession-in-next-js-13-beta-server-component-in-a/75909810?noredirect=1#comment134020339_75909810)